# Round Robin in non-preemptive?

Tags: operating-system, round-robin, preemptive

In my exam question paper,teacher asked to *calculate the average waiting time and turnaround time with round robin scheduling algorithm both for preemptive and non-preemptive approach*.

Here,i did the preemptive approach it's okay. but when i try to find out non-preemptive it confused me it becomes *FCFS*. is it valid in round robin algorithm with non-preemptive approach?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, Round Robin is the preemptive approach to FCFS, and FCFS is the non-preemptive approach to Round Robin. Other than that the algorithms have almost everything in common. Though I would still say that Round Robin is distinctly different from FCFS due to its preemptiveness.

"If time quantum becomes infinity, Round Robin scheduling algorithm gradually becomes a FCFS scheduling algorithm."